# Git- Delete local copy from server

Tags: git, github

Just curious, can i delete the local copy of a client from GitHub or from my system. I am the owner of this git repository. The target user is working on a branch under my repository. So can i delete his branch of this user along with his local code?

Comment: I don't get what your target is. Do you just want to delete YOUR local copy or do you want to delete HER/HIS local copy of a branch? The latter isn't possible, the other part ... well just use whatever you want to delete it?

Comment: @Seth I wanna delete HIS/HER copy of a branch

Comment: @Seth Thanks you just answered my question anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know GIT is a decentralized version control system. As such you don't have a central repository and every copy of the repository can be handled in whatever way the person that made it seems fit.

You can't "push" the removal of a branch to someone and you might have any number of branches in your local repository that no other party knows about because they never fetched them from you/you never pushed it to a designated "master" repository.

What could work is that you remove the branch from the designated master repository and hope that the other user fetches those changes in a way that removes the branch from his repository. An example would be that he deletes his local copy and just has to fetch the whole project again. Other than that you're at the "mercy" of the behavior of that third party.